# WPF. How to list the 4 best combinations inside 4 different labels

Tags: c#, wpf, label

With the following code I´m able to obtain ,each time a key is pressed and one by one, the best combinations of power supplies (including quantity of each model) needed to support a certain amount of watts (`totalwatios`).

Instead of using `Console.WriteLine` How can i add the first four combinations to four different labels (inside its `Label.Content`? .

Thanks in advance.

```
        fuentes fuente2 = new fuentes { referencia = "CE18M", modelo = "MEANWELL", voltaje = 12, potencia = 18, ip = 67, factorpotencia = 0.5, precio = 14 };
        fuentes fuente7 = new fuentes { referencia = "CE36M", modelo = "MEANWELL", voltaje = 12, potencia = 36, ip = 67, factorpotencia = 0.5, precio = 26 };
        fuentes fuente9 = new fuentes { referencia = "CE60M", modelo = "MEANWELL", voltaje = 12, potencia = 60, ip = 67, factorpotencia = 0.5, precio = 29.5 };
        fuentes fuente14 = new fuentes { referencia = "CE120M", modelo = "MEANWELL", voltaje = 12, potencia = 120, ip = 67, factorpotencia = 0.5, precio = 76.62 };


        List<double> units = new List<double>();
        List<double> fuentesexterior = new List<double>() { fuente14.potencia, fuente12.potencia, fuente9.potencia, fuente7.potencia, fuente2.potencia};
        calculofuentesexterior(units, fuentesexterior, 0, 0, totalwatios);
    }
    static void calculofuentesexterior(List<double> units, List<double> fuentesexterior, double highest, double sum, double goal)
    {
        if (sum <= (goal + (goal * 25 / 100)) && sum >= (goal + (goal * 15 / 100)))
        {
            pintafuentesexterior(units, fuentesexterior);
            return;
        }
        if (sum > (goal + (goal * 25 / 100)))
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (double value in fuentesexterior)
        {
            if (value >= highest)
            {
                List<double> copy = new List<double>(units);
                copy.Add(value);
                calculofuentesinterior(copy, fuentesexterior, value, sum + value, goal);
            }
        }
    }

    static void pintafuentesexterior(List<double> units, List<double> amounts)
    {
        foreach (double fuentesexterior in amounts)
        {
            double count = units.Count(value => value == fuentesexterior);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
                fuentesexterior,
                count);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When u create Label in XAML you can add Property

> x:Name="Label1"

Create 4 Label elements with names that ends with 1,2,3 and 4;
So in code behind in your loop

```
static void pintafuentesexterior(List<double> units, List<double> amounts)
{
    int x=1;
    foreach (double fuentesexterior in amounts)
    {

        double count = units.Count(value => value == fuentesexterior);

       Label label = (Label)this.FindName("labelName"+x);
       label.Content=sting.Format("{0}:{1}",fuentesexterior,count);
       x++;
    }
```

Comment: `this` can´t be used with static properties. How can i modify the code to be working?

Comment: just remove static